# missing /etc/yum.conf and /var/cache/yum on Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, yum

According to the book I am reading, yum stores settings in `/etc/yum.conf` file and stores downloaded packages in `/var/cache/yum` folder.

Neither of these two files/folders is present in my fresh install of Fedora 25. Any idea where should I look to get access to these files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`yum` has been superseded by `dnf` in Fedora.  `dnf` provides better dependency resolution but otherwise mirrors `yum` commands very closely.  Look at `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` and `/var/cache/dnf`.  Oddly, `/etc/yum.repos.d` still contains the repositories you configure.

More information can be found at [Using the DNF software package manager](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF?rd=Dnf)